# Prove that a semi-complete directed graph has a directed cycle if and only if it has a directed triangle (directed cycle of length 3).

Tags: graph-theory

This is a problem on my textbook that i have difficulty to deal with.

Prove that a semi-complete directed graph has a directed cycle if and only if it has
a directed triangle (directed cycle of length 3).

Comment: What is your definition of semi-complete digraph?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming standard(?) definition that a semi-complete digraph is a digraph that has at least one arc between
every two vertices.

One direction is trivial.

The other direction:
let $v_1 \ldots v_nv_1$ be a directed cycle of minimal length.
If $n=3$ we are done.
Assume $n>3$.
There is at least one arc between $v_1$ and $v_3$.
If this is $v_3v_1$ then we have found a directed cycle $v_1v_2v_3v_1$ of length 3. Contradiction.
If it is $v_1v_3$, then $v_1v_3\ldots v_nv_1$ is a directed cycle of length $n-1$. Contradiction.